# How to monkey patch a third-party Angular component to remove a HostListener

Tags: angular, monkeypatching

Our team heavily relies on an internal Angular component library which unfortunately has a component with a `window:scroll` HostListener attached. This HostListener triggers change detection every time the page scrolls, killing our app's performance.

Unfortunately, the team responsible for maintaining this library does not seem to have the capacity to work on fixing this component anytime soon, but since our application does not care about the functionality provided by the HostListener, we were hoping it would be possible to monkey patch the HostListener away for this particular component.

Monkey patching the function itself by redefining the field on the prototype works of course, but this doesn't stop the HostListener from firing and triggering change detection which is where the actual performance issues come from.

If it matters, our application is on Angular 10, although we hope to upgrade soon.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you know the function "attached" to the hostListener, you can
   create a directive -in the code it's called "onScroll" and the
   component is "HelloComponent"

   ```
   @Directive({
     selector: '[nullScroll]',
   })
   export class NullScrollDirective {
     constructor(private helloComponent: HelloComponent) {
       if (this.helloComponent['onScroll']) {
         this.helloComponent['onScroll'] = () => {
           return null;
         };
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   then use

   ```
   <hello nullScroll ...></hello>
   ```
2. You can also check the fonts of the components -if is a library
   should be in node_modules- and remove the @HostListener. Take
   account that if you update the library, you should change again the hostListener
3. I don't know if was possible create a component that extend from
   this component and change the hostListener by a fromEvent rxjs
   operator using a debounce pipe

Comment: 1 is pretty similar to what we tried, but unfortunately it doesn't actually remove the Host Listener itself or its behavior of bubbling up change detection cycles to the parent which is what's ultimately causing our performance woes.